# How to download an image from cloud fire store

Tags: flutter

I wanna know how to get the download URL from the cloud firestore(I am not using storage) I saw a lot to tutorial but I cant find a solution, I am still a newbie when it comes to firebase, I saved the URL in the collection of cloud firestore, I displayed that image to my app but I don't know how to download that particular image which I displayed, I need help

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Add a minimal code example for example.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a cloud function to parse the Url of the Image created in Firebase Storage and parse it into Firestore.

Cloud Functions are made on Node.js for firebase

Below is sample code written in javascript

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const db = require('firebase-admin');
db.initializeApp();
exports.sendUrl = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => 
    {
    let firstPartUrl = object.mediaLink.split("?")[0] // 


'https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/abcbucket.appspot.com/o/son 
  gs%2Fsong1.mp3.mp3'
    const secondPartUrl = object.mediaLink.split("?")[1] // 'generation=123445678912345&alt=media'

firstPartUrl = firstPartUrl.replace("https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com")
firstPartUrl = firstPartUrl.replace("v1", "v0")

firstPartUrl += "?" + secondPartUrl.split("&")[1]; // 'alt=media'
firstPartUrl += "&token=" + object.metadata.firebaseStorageDownloadTokens
console.info('image Url:' , firstPartUrl);
console.info('image path', object.name);

let data = {
    image2: firstPartUrl
};

db.firestore().collection('Students').doc(object.name).set(
  {
    image: firstPartUrl,
  } );
```

});